# How do you Create a Start and End with CFSCRIPT for a CFLOOP From an RSS FEED Query?

Tags: coldfusion, rss, cfml, cfquery, cfloop

I am attempting to create a QofQ that already functions properly with normal cf tags. But the change is using normal cf tags and converting it to cfscript functionality. **cffeed action="read" source="#source#/feed/" query="rssFeed"**

There is a cf query loop that wraps around a structure. The one structure is defined outside of the cf query loop and so is the array. The item[currentRow] is contained inside of the cf query loop while the result is the RSS Feed Information. For example query='rssFeed'.

```
enter code here

cfset myStruct = structNew()
cfset myStruct.item = arrayNew(1)

cfloop query="rssFeed"
cfset myStruct.item[currentRow] = structNew()
cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid = structNew()
cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].guid.isPermaLink = 'true'
cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].title = xmlFormat(rssFeed.TITLE)
cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].comments.value =  xmlFormat(rssFeed.COMMENTS)
cfset myStruct.item[currentRow].link = xmlFormat(rssFeed.RSSLINK)
cfloop
```

The next cf loop is supposed to output the rssFeed Results one to four. It works properly with normal cf query loop, basically it is a QofQ with a start row and end row set on the second cf query loop. The arrayNew() is the list of items from the RSS Feed tag with a query of rssFeed. The start row and end row must be set on the second cf query loop and output.

```
enter code here

cfloop query="rssFeed" startrow="1" endrow="4"
itemprop="url" href="#rssFeed.RSSLINK#" title="#rssFeed.TITLE#" class="feedBlock">#rssFeed.TITLE#
cfloop
```

I made the code shorter for posting purposes and managed to find one solution, but is not the solution of code I am searching for as an end result.

What I managed to create in cfsctipt works, but I am trying to further break it down. A working example of cfscript:

**EXAMPLE 1:**

```
enter code here

*cfscript*

// Define our query

one = ["#rssFeed.TITLE[1]#,#rssFeed.CONTENT[1]#,#rssFeed.RSSLINK[1]#"];

myQuery = queryNew(" "); 

queryAddColumn(myQuery, "one", "CF_SQL_VARCHAR", one); 

// By row index 

for (i = 1; i <= myQuery.recordCount; i++){
writeOutput("<ul><li>#rssFeed.TITLE[1]#,#rssFeed.CONTENT[1]#,#rssFeed.RSSLINK[1]#</li></ul>
");

}

// By query 

for (row in myQuery) { 
writeOutput("<li>#row.one#</li>");

}

*cfscript*
```

**EXAMPLE 2:**

```
enter code here

// Define our query

myQuery = queryNew("title,content,link", "varchar,varchar,varchar",   [["#rssFeed.TITLE#"],["#rssFeed.CONTENT#"],["#rssFeed.RSSLINK#"]]);


i = 1;
startRow = 1;
endRow = 4;

thisQuery = queryNew('#myQuery.columnlist#');

while (i lte myQuery.recordcount)
    {

    if(++i gte startRow && i lt endRow)
        {

            queryAddRow(thisQuery,1);
            c = 0;
            while (++c lte listLen('#myQuery.columnlist#'))
             {

              QuerySetCell(thisQuery, listGetAt('#myQuery.columnlist#',c), myQuery[listGetAt('#myQuery.columnlist#',c)][1], thisQuery.recordCount);


             }

        }

}

WriteDump(thisQuery);


writeOutput("<ul><li>#not sue of what output#</li><li>#not sure of what output#</li></ul>");
```

I am attempting to convert the code from normal cf tags to cfscript as part of a website upgrade and further advancing of my programming knowledge. I appreciate your time and if you don't feel like assisting with it, no problem.

Comment: If your examples work, what is your question?

Comment: Also, it looks like your code got mangled.  To post tag based code, use the code button in the toolbar, ie `{}` or indent four or more spaces.